# No scrolling on my Vaio VPCEF3E1E Notebook

Tags: touchpad, sony, vaio

I have a big problem with my Sony Vaio VPCEF3E1E touch-pad. I can't scroll. Since I'm a new Ubuntu user, I have no idea where I can find an answer. I have found no answer in the mouse options either.

Answer (score 1):

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1722177 any help?

> Add the following line to `/etc/modprobe.d/psmouse.conf`
>
> ```
>     "options psmouse proto=imps"
> ```

Comment: In other words: Add the following line to */etc/modprobe.d/psmouse.conf*

"options psmouse proto=imps"

Comment: I dont have a config file there thats called psmouse.conf....and I cant create one cause ubuntu says I'm not the root user or something.

Answer (score 0):

To use the scrolling capability of the touch-pad, the drivers have to be installed, even with Windows. Sony most likely doesn't provide drivers for Linux so you will just have to use the up and down arrows or the "page up" and "page down" buttons on your keyboard.

To fix this, I would suggest buying a laptop mouse. :)